# order by with union in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, union

I want to use order by statement that provide me result of top.

```
$sql_ins = "select user_first_name, user_last_name, user_id from user 
            INNER JOIN xyz on user_id=s_id 
            where (s_id='".$_SESSION['user']."' OR r_id='".$_SESSION['user']."')
              AND user_id!='".$_SESSION['user']."' group by user_id

            UNION

            SELECT user_first_name, user_last_name, user_id from user 
            INNER JOIN xyz on user_id=r_id 
            WHERE (r_id='".$_SESSION['user']."' OR s_id='".$_SESSION['user']."')
              AND user_id!='".$_SESSION['user']."' 

            GROUP BY user_id";
```

I want to get output by order by id desc but the output is an error.

Comment: Please provide the final SQL Query after this `echo $sql_ins`. And what error you get. Without that no one can help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query it's worked for me....

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT content_update.id as id, 
             content_update.course_id as course_id, 
             content_update.status as status, 
             content_update.title as title, 
             content_update.img_src as img, 
             content_update.entry_date as entry_date 
      FROM content_update 

      UNION ALL 

      SELECT video_update.id as id, 
             video_update.course_id as course_id, 
             video_update.status as status,
             video_update.title as title, 
             video_update.video_link as img, 
             video_update.entry_date as entry_date 
      FROM video_update ) results 

ORDER BY entry_date DESC
```

Comment: @AshishYadav dude please use carefully it's working for me I am use this in my Live project